# Why is the instantaneous height of water waves in double split experiment expressed in complex number?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

This picture is a screenshot of a lecture of Feynman explaining the double slit experiment with electrons. The paragraph is quite confusing. It says something of a "mathematical trick" in using the complex numbers. What is that trick exactly?

Comment: You forgot to add the picture.

Comment: Perhaps that complex numbers are a 'trick' to express amplitude and phase in one (albeit complex) number. With the proper math background there is no 'trick', and Feynman knew math quite well, but also knew how to keep people engaged with his lectures.

Comment: If the question is about electron interference, why mention water waves in the title?

Comment: You must complete the chapter to get that; did you really read it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP shows no research efforts.

Comment: Also, did you read the required chapters of Vol I? I doubt that.

Comment: Electron interference and water-wave interference are quite similar. That is why.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 I completed the chapter, yes. I and REALLY read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complex number is a **scaled rotation in two dimensions** and **rotations represent the simplest waves** through a bit of trickery.

## Complex numbers are scaled rotations.

The exact reason why is a bit of trickery in its own right, so I have to share this with you even though you might lack the mathematical background. The point here is, the addition and multiplication rules created when you add the number $i = \sqrt{-1}$ to your number system, considering as "numbers" the points $(x, y) = x + i y,$ contains addition-of-points $(a, b) + (c, d) = (a + c, b + d)$ and multiplication-of-points (using the distributive rule, since $i \times i = -1$) of $(a, b)\times(c,d) = (ac-bd, ad + bc).$ These rules take a special form: multiplication is a *linear transformation* of that point $(c, d),$ and like all linear transformations, it can be written as a matrix expression.

As a matrix acting on the vector $\begin{bmatrix}c\\d\end{bmatrix}$ this is the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a & -b\\b & a\end{bmatrix}.$ Furthermore we can also express $\begin{bmatrix}c\\d\end{bmatrix}$ as the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}c&-d\\d&c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and put off that projection matrix on the right indefinitely... so for example as a normal matrix product, we would find our "multiplication rule" above as the standard matrix multiplication: $$\begin{bmatrix}a & -b\\b & a\end{bmatrix}~\begin{bmatrix}c & -d\\d & c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}ac-bd & -ad-bc\\ad+bc & ac-bd\end{bmatrix}.$$And our addition rule is just matrix addition! Happy day. But the point is that when we peek at the innards we see that this sign pattern looks an awful lot like the rotation matrices that we know and love, $\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$. In fact the only problem is that we know $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$ whereas $a^2 + b^2$ can be any number; but this just means that there is a $\theta$ (technically the $\tan^{-1}(b/a)$) and an $R$ (technically $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$) such that these matrices are $$\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix} = R \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}.$$

So every complex number is a scaled rotation (created by its multiplication action on the complex plane: it scales and rotates), which can also be added like any matrix can (take the point $[1;0]$ and see where both scaled rotations map it, as a representation of each complex number--now add the resulting points together by their components like any vectors add, then think about the scaled rotation which takes $[1;0]$ to that new point: this is the sum of the two scaled rotations).

Some obvious things follow, like that the product of two complex numbers has a scale factor (or "modulus") which is the product of the scale factors, and an angle which is the sum of the angles, of the original numbers. These are both commutative so complex multiplication is commutative; also since matrix mathematics is trivially associative and distributes over addition, complex multiplication is associative and distributes over addition. All of these rules make up the basics of what we expect before we call something a "number", which is why these things are called "complex numbers."

## Scaled rotations are waves.

This is probably closer to the actual "trick" that Feynman meant. The simplest way to get waves are sinusoids like $\cos$ and $\sin$. Whenever you see a $\cos$, you can imagine that it secretly comes from a rotation, as happens most visibly in a crankshaft:

[image: An animation of a crankshaft where a red bar travels around in a circle, a blue bar transmits this to a block sliding left-to-right, and some gray plates force the block to move in one-dimension.]

The red block on the right is describing a nice wavy sinusoidal motion left-to-right. In fact it is a perfect sine wave, if the blue bar is infinitely long compared to the radius of the red bar at left which is travelling in a circle. The block on the right moves exactly the distance of the size of the circle on the left, which is the scaling factor of the complex number. So in this way we take something complicated -- a sine wave in time -- and turn it into something simpler, a scaled rotation with a constant scale factor and a constantly-increasing angle.

The technical tool is to take a complex number and pull out its "real" component: $$\Re~(a, b) = a = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = R \cos\theta.$$

To make a wave move forward in space as time goes forward, we just take the formula which makes any function-in-space $f(x)$ move forward in space as time moves forward, $f(x - v t).$ But whereas with just plain cosines you would have to write $$f(x, t) = R \cos(k x - \omega t) = R \cos(k x) \cos(\omega t) - R \sin(k x) \sin(\omega t)$$ and things get very hard to write very quickly, with complex numbers you can instead write $f(x, t) = \Re \phi(x, t)$ where $\phi(x, t) = R ~ e^{i(kx - \omega t)} = R e^{i k x} e^{-i \omega t},$ which is just a lot less to write. You haven't technically lost anything, but the analysis usually becomes about 10 times simpler. (I have not proven that $e^{i\theta}$ is the rotation matrix by angle $\theta$, of course; that's a subject for a whole other question and comment.)

So that's the trick: take any "real" oscillation, invent an "imaginary" dimension which nobody can see, and since this is your little playground you make the thing also oscillate properly in the imaginary way: then if you've done it right, you can combine those together into one "complex" dimension where the thing is merely rotating, analyze the problem with that complex dimension, get the correct answer in terms of complex numbers, then when you're done with analysis, take the "real part" and you get the right answer with a lot less trigonometry.

Comment: This really answers my question and I understand almost all of it. Thank you.

Comment: @RabailKhan: You're welcome! I confess that I had a lot of similar questions about complex numbers in my undergraduate work at Cornell, and I was just "lucky" to have professors who could similarly say "here's the simple top-level stuff which you're missing which unifies everything together into a nice package." So I saw that you seemed to be having a similar confusion, and I'm happy to "pay it forward."

Comment: @CRDrost, Hey  Chris, I knew you would answer it; and the answer is explicitly elaborateness and intuitive as usual in your answer. +1.

Comment: @RabailKhan: If you really think this answer helped you; then please upvote it and also, (if you like) accept it by clicking on the _tick_ symbol beneath the  score bar.