# What does the $e^{i\omega t}$ notation mean in Feynman's water wave thought experiment?

Tags: waves, definition, notation

Excerpt from the Feynman Lectures, Volume III, [Quantum Behavior](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_01.html):

> You will remember that the quantitative relationship between $I_1$, $I_2$, and $I{_1}{_2}$ can be expressed in the following way: The instantaneous height of the water wave at the detector for the wave from hole 1 can be written as (the real part of) $\hat{h}_1e^{i\omega t}$, where the “amplitude” h1 is, in general, a complex number.

Here's Figure 1-2:

[image: Figure 1-2]

Nowhere it is explained what the $e$, $i$, $\omega$ and $t$ symbols represent. What are they and how are they related to Figure 1-2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Notation

- $e$ is [Euler's number](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/e-eulers-number.html)
- $i$ is the [unit imaginary number](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/imaginary-numbers.html) (recall that complex numbers have a real part and an imaginary part)
- $\omega$ is the Greek letter [Omega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega)
- $t$ is simply a unit of time
- $\omega t$ is the [angular frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency) of the waveform measured in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) per second

### Explanation

The reason why the instantaneous height of the water wave is ~$\hat{h}_1e^{i\omega t}$ is because waves can be considered to be scaled rotations, and scaled rotations can be computed with complex numbers. Refer to this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/277414/172146) by user CR Drost for a deep dive into the mathematics behind Feynman's formula.